# Why the function .then() is not been executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read a value from the firebase database and I am stuck. When I try to snapshot the value, the function .then() is not been executed.

This is the code.

```
function checkPublishButton(){
  $( "#publish_button" ).click(function(){
  //Check if a user is logged in.
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    //Declare firebase data-base
    var database = firebase.database();      
    //Get user's total event created counter
    return database.ref("users/" + user.uid ).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log("This is not executing");
      return snapshot.val().total_event_created;
    }).then(function(counter) {
      //Increase the total_event_counter by one
      console.log("This is also not executing");
      var counter = counter +1;
      database.ref('users/'+user_id+'/total_event_created').set(counter);  
      //Get input from form
      var title = $("#title").val();
      var date = $("#date").val();
      var hour = $("#hour").val();
      var place = $("#place").val();
      var brief_description = $("#brief_description").val();
      var detailed_description = $("#detailed_description").val();
      var contact_email = $("#contact_email").val();
      var contact_phone_number = $("#contact_phone_number").val();
      var imageUrl = $("#imageUrl").val(); 
      //Post event into firebase database
      database.ref('events/' + user_id + '/' +  counter).set({
        title: title,
        date: date,
        hour: hour,
        place: place,
        brief_description: brief_description,
        detailed_description: detailed_description,
        contact_email: contact_email,
        contact_phone_number: contact_phone_number,
        imageUrl: imageUrl
      });
    });              
  });
});
}
```

So, you can have an idea, both codes since the console.log() commands are not been executed.

Comment: try printing `users/+user.uid` and check if url is correct or not

Comment: Likely because one of the promises is being rejected, possibly from an error being thrown. To review the rejection reason, add a [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) callback to the end of the method chain and inspect its argument.

Comment: @PriyeshKumar, I checked the url and its correct.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, I tried it, and the catch method do not execute either.

Comment: I have been stuck for days in this part of the project.

Comment: Are you authenticated? If not, the code will not run.

Comment: Following on the comment from @Jay, is the `onAuthStateChanged` callback being invoked?

Comment: Yeah! The code will not work. Since you written all your code inside the onAuthStateChanged callback, it only calls when there is a change in the authentication state. (user login/ logout)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! The code will not work. Since you written all your code inside the onAuthStateChanged callback, it only calls when there is a change in the authentication state. (user login/ logout). Here I have refactored your code a bit.Hope this helps you.

```
var isUserAuthed = false;
var user = null;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(newUser) {
  isUserAuthed = true;
  user = newUser;
})

function checkPublishButton() {
  $("#publish_button").click(function() {
    //Check if a user is logged in.
    if(isUserAuthed){
      //Declare firebase data-base
      var database = firebase.database();
      //Get user's total event created counter
      return database.ref("users/" + user.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log("This is not executing");
        return snapshot.val().total_event_created;
      }).then(function(counter) {
        //Increase the total_event_counter by one
        console.log("This is also not executing");
        var counter = counter + 1;
        database.ref('users/' + user_id + '/total_event_created').set(counter);
        //Get input from form
        var title = $("#title").val();
        var date = $("#date").val();
        var hour = $("#hour").val();
        var place = $("#place").val();
        var brief_description = $("#brief_description").val();
        var detailed_description = $("#detailed_description").val();
        var contact_email = $("#contact_email").val();
        var contact_phone_number = $("#contact_phone_number").val();
        var imageUrl = $("#imageUrl").val();
        //Post event into firebase database
        database.ref('events/' + user_id + '/' + counter).set({
          title: title,
          date: date,
          hour: hour,
          place: place,
          brief_description: brief_description,
          detailed_description: detailed_description,
          contact_email: contact_email,
          contact_phone_number: contact_phone_number,
          imageUrl: imageUrl
        });
      });
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I just finished implementing this way. I got inside the if(userIsAuthed) but console.log("This is not executing"); is not executing.